# Resize video while live streaming with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

My server uses this command to stream a video (1280x544):

```
ffmpeg -re -i c:\ffmpeg\This.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -movflags faststart -f mpegts tcp://192.168.1.82:1234?listen
```

Now, I would like to reduce the original resolution while streaming. I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -re -y -i this.mp4 -vf scale="480:-1" this480.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -movflags faststart -f mpegts tcp://192.168.1.82:1235?listen
```

but the resolution does not change.

Can this be done or I am asking the impossible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanted to resize your video (`-vf scale="480:-1"`), and at the same time you wanted don't to use a video codec for encoding such resized video (`-vcodec copy`).

It's impssible — video codec `copy` means no decoding, no encoding, no filtering - simply *copying without any change.* It is not a real codec.

Try omitting `-vcodec copy` to enable FFmpeg to choose an appropriate codec.

Comment: OK thanks. Based on your comments, I was able to resize and to live stream using:
ffmpeg -re -i this.mp4 -vf scale="480:-1" -movflags faststart -f mpegts tcp://192.168.1.82:1235?listen